# Default Document does not exist

Tags: iis, iis-7, bugzilla

I've created a new application under my Default Web Site with the IIS manager in order to set up Bugzilla, and according to the instructions here: https://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/iis.html#iis
I supposed to add something to the Default Document, which isn't exist at all.

I'm running on Windows 7 Ultimate and using IIS 7.5, and according to the official site - http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument - this version of IIS includes the Default Document. Also the guide is based on exactly my version of Windows. I'm running the IIS manager as administrator.

I can't find any similar problem to the one I face in Stack Overflow or in Google. Any YouTube or Google guide I watched had this Defualt Document in the home pane.

Comment: Ensure that **all** of the options under "Add Features to Windows" > IIS are selected. Do not accept the defaults. Also please post a screenshot of the Features window.

Comment: Thank you @Dai, I checked my features and the Default Document was unchecked! I never installed it, it just came that way with Windows. Many thanks again!

Comment: Note: Even with the "Default Document" feature checked, I have found that the "default.aspx" document might still be missing.  This is possible if the IIS install had a previous history such as being used to host PHP sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Reposting my comment as an Answer)

Ensure that *all* of the options under "Add Features to Windows" > IIS are selected. Do not accept the defaults as most options are not selected by default.

[image].